# How to bind decorators with Ninject from outside in?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, decorator

I use ninject bindings with `WhenInjectedInto<>` to bind decorators from inside out. However, from different entry points I need different features, maybe run in different sequence, so I would like to bind the decorators chain from outside in. Is this possible with Ninject?

**Eg.** I would live to achieve this:

```
Bind<IFooService>().To<SimpleService>().WhenInjectedInto<FeatureAFooServiceDecorator>();
Bind<IFooService>().To<FeatureAFooServiceDecorator>().WhenInjectedInto<FeatureBFooServiceDecorator>();
Bind<IFooService>().To<FeatureBFooServiceDecorator>().WhenInjectedInto<EntryPoint1>();

Bind<IFooService>().To<SimpleService>().WhenInjectedInto<FeatureBFooServiceDecorator>();
Bind<IFooService>().To<FeatureBFooServiceDecorator>().WhenInjectedInto<EntryPoint2>();
```

But this is not correct, because `FeatureBFooServiceDecorator` is not clear what it will get injected (`FeatureAFooServiceDecorator` or `SimpleService`).

I suppose the solution would be to get things binded the other way round like:

**pseudocode**

```
For<EntryPoint1>().Use<FeatureBFooServiceDecorator>().ThenUse<FeatureAFooServiceDecorator>().ThenUse<SimpleService>();
For<EntryPoint2>().Use<FeatureBFooServiceDecorator>().ThenUse<SimpleService>();
```

**Edit:**

To achieve this manually, I would do:

```
var entryPoint1 = new EntryPoint1(new FeatureBFooServiceDecorator(new FeatureAFooServiceDecorator(new SimpleService)));
var entryPoint2 = new EntryPoint2(new FeatureBFooServiceDecorator(new SimpleService));
```

(Of course I would avoid newing up things, because these classes have couple of more dependencies each, some of which are `InRequestScope` or `InNamedScope`)

**Note:** For the above example, asume that there are these classes:

```
public interface IFooService {/*...*/}
public class SimpleService : IFooService {/*...*/}
public class FeatureAFooServiceDecorator : IFooService
{
    private readonly IFooService _innerFooService;

    public FeatureAFooServiceDecorator(IFooService fooService) {
        _innerFooService = fooService;
    }
}

public class FeatureBFooServiceDecorator : IFooService {/*...same as above...*/}

public class EntryPoint1{
    public EntryPoint1(IFooService fooService){/*...*/}
}


public class EntryPoint2{
    public EntryPoint2(IFooService fooService){/*...*/}
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Can you update your code with how you would wire this up manually without Ninject, i.e. with a bunch of `new` statements?

Answer (score 1):

So i gather what you want to do is

```
public class FeatureBFooService : IFooService
{
    public FeatureBFooService(IFooService service1, IFooService service2)
    { ...}
}

var service = new FeatureBFooService(new FeatureAFooService(), new SimpleService());
```

(of course you don't want to do the `new`'s yourself). So you are using the same interface multiple times, even for the same constructor, but want not only different instances but different types (`FeatureAFooService`, `SimpleService`) injected into the constructor of `FeatureBFooService`.

There's two ways i can think of how you can achieve this.
But to be honest, i ought to warn you that this seems quite complicated. Usually this means the design is not ideal and you'd be better of thinking about how to solve the problem differently. After all, when the implementation share the same interface, shouldn't they be doing about the same thing? It would be one thing to inject a collection of `IFooService` into a class whose using all these services, but that that class itself again is a `IFooService` seems a bit strange.
But enough said, i believe in people making their own choices - and sometimes mistakes - because that's the best way to learn. And of course i may also be wrong in my assumptions and what you're striving for is the best achievable solution.

---

**Solution 1: `.ToConstructor()` binding**

```
Bind<IFooService>().ToConstructor(ctorArg => new FeatureBFooService(ctorArg.Inject<FeatureAFooService>(), ctorArg.Inject<SimpleService>()));
```

for every constructor parameter you can define what should get injected. This way you don't rely on a binding and can determine what get's injected for a given type.

---

**Solution 2: [Named] binding**

adapt the implementation as follows:

```
public const string FeatureAService = "FeatureA";
public const string SimpleService = "Simple";

public class FeatureBFooService : IFooService
{
    public FeatureBFooService(
               [Named(FeatureAService)]I FooService service1, 
               [Named(SimpleService] IFooService service2)
    { ...}
}

Bind<IFooService>().To<FeatureAService>().Named(FeatureAService);
Bind<IFooService>().To<SimpleService>().Named(SimpleService);
```

---

**Solution 3: `.ToProvider()` binding + custom binding logic**

What you could also do, is to do

```
Bind<IFooService>().ToProvider<FooServiceProvider>();
```

where `FooServiceProvider` will - according to you custom logic - decide what exact dependency is to be instanciated. It could then either do

```
IResolutionRoot.Get<FeatureAFooService>();
```

or you could still make use of the `[Named]` feature:

```
IResolutionRoot.Get<IFooService>(FeatureAService);
```

It could then, for example, look like (pseudo code):

```
public class FooServiceProvider : Provider<IFooService>
{
    protected override IFooService CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
       Type returnType = DetermineImplementationType(context);

       switch(returnType)
       {
           case typeof(FeatureBFooService):
               return CreateFeatureBFooService(context);
               break:
           default:
               throw new NotSupportedException(...);
       }
    }

    private static Type DetermineImplementationType(IContext context)
    {
       // your custom logic here
    }

    private static IFooService CreateFeatureBFooService(IContext context)
    {
        var dependency1 = context.Kernel.Get<IFooService>(FeatureAFooService);
        var dependency2 = context.Kernel.Get<IFooService>(SimpleService);
        return context.Kernel.Get<IFooService>(
                   FeatureBFooService,
                   new ConstructorArgument("service1", dependency1),
                   new ConstructorArgument("service2", dependency2));
    }
}
```

Note that with `ConstructorArgument`, the value is injected into the constructor parameter matching the name (`service1`, `service2`), so that's a refactor-trap.
Also note that you can also use `IContext.Kernel.ContextPreservingGet<>` if you need to preserve the context. However, that's only available with the extension ninject.extensions.ContextPreservation.